# Вылазит ошибка IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
point = input() 
point = point.split()
point = list(map(int, point))

i=0

while (len(point))>(len(point)-1):
    if point[i] == point[i+1] and (point[1] == point[-1]):
        print('Yes')
        quit()
    else:
        i+=1

print('No')
```

решаю задачку, вот только не пойму почему вылазит ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source.py", line 8, in <module>
    if point[i] == point[i+1] and (point[1] == point[-1]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: а можете описать задачу, возможно есть более "стандартные" решения для нее.

Answer (score 2):

1. Условие вашего цикла всегда истинно, замените его на это `i < len(point)-1`
2. Придерживайтесь единого стиля кодирования. Если взяли 2ю часть логического выражения в скобки, то возьмите и 1ю в скобки `(point[i] == point[i+1]) and (point[1] == point[-1])`.
3. `else` можно не писать, т.к. в случае выполнения условия, вы сразу выйдите из программы.
4. Первые три строки обычно записывают "вместе".
5. `len(point)-1` лучше сохранить в переменной, чтобы не пересчитывать, что называется "за зря".
6. Еще проверку `point[1] == point[-1]` можно вынести за цикл (это несколько оптимизирует работу программы).

Финал:

```
point = list(map(int, input().split()))
if point[1] == point[-1]:
    i, max_i = 0, len(point) - 1
    while i < max_i:
        if point[i] == point[i+1]:
            print('Yes')
            quit()
        i += 1

print('No')
```

Comment: также если `var == False` то можно по циклу вообще не проходить

Comment: @Danis, точно. сейчас добавлю. спасибо

Answer (score 1):

`(len(point))>(len(point)-1)` всегда `True`

```
point = input() 
point = point.split()
point = list(map(int, point))

i=0

while i < len(point) - 1:
    if point[i] == point[i+1] and (point[1] == point[-1]):
        print('Yes')
        quit()
    else:
        i+=1

print('No')
```